# How Remove middle UIViewController from presentation stack

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I am an experienced iOS developer, but I've stumbled upon an issue that I'm not entirely sure how to solve.

Lets say for example I have 3 UIViewControllers, A, B, and C respectively.  A is the root and B is presented on top of A and C is presented on top of B.

B and C are presented using presentViewController:animated:completion:
So the presentation stack looks like this.

[A] -> [B] -> [C]

In my program, I want to dismiss B and only B.  The docs for 
dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: says that if I dismiss B, it will ask its A to dismiss B and then will also dismiss C as well.  I do not want that.  I want to dismiss B only such that A will choose C as its presentedViewController like so

[A] -> [C]

Is this possible?

--------Notes-------

I realize that this seems more suited for another presentation pattern where A,B,C would be siblings under a common parentViewController.  But I May not use that.

The presentedViewController/presentingViewController pattern is just like a doublylinked list.  However, since these properties are read-only, I can not do any node manipulation.

Comment: seems like add subview which mimic presentation animation would be solution

Comment: Why do you need to dismiss just B? Why not wait until you need to dismiss C and then dismiss B (which will also dismiss C)?

Comment: Because B will no longer be used and I don't want it to stick around in memory.

Comment: Maybe you could dismiss view controller B & C without animation and then present another C without animation. Not quite correct though.

Comment: If I do that then it will dealloc C.  Forcing me to save all my data some where.  Then if I present it again it will call viewDidLoad again and make sure it's populated with the data I saved prior.  Not only that.  C will flicker For a brief second.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a navigation controller with the navigation bar hidden and push the controllers rather than present them (using a push and pop animation that mimics that of presentation). 
Then use setViewControllers to replace the ABC stack with an AC stack?

Comment: You read the post before it was complete. I said " and push the controllers rather than present them (using a push and pop animation that mimics that of presentation)"

Comment: But this results in unwanted back buttons that don't appear when presented instead of pushed.

Comment: So the back buttons also appear even if the navigation bar is hidden?

Comment: Obviously not. But you don't know if the OP needs the nab bar or not. Most likely the OP does to show a title and a button or two.

Comment: I don't know and thats why I didn't make that assumption and my response begins with "Could you" and ends with a question mark. Therefore  implicitly enquiring if such an approach would fit in with the OPs existing requirements and architecture.

Comment: The navigation controller provides a parent child relationship of which I may not do.  The issue with this pattern is when I choose to present a view controller on one of the children.  Instead of presenting it on the child it actually presents it on the parent.  This creates a bit of a problem when the top viewController needs to interact with the viewController that presented it.  Cause the top viewController will think the navigationController is the parent when actually the child called the presentViewController: